# OnMonthChange event

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, fullcalendar

I am trying to implement the following: by default (at page's start) I fill the list of events with the array. After that if user wants to change the month or year I want to retrieve the events via AJAX call and re-fill the events property of the fullcalendar.

Here is the init code:

```
function initializeCalendar(year, month, events) {
            $('#orders-calendar').fullCalendar({
                header: {
                    left: 'prev,next',
                    center: 'title',
                    right: ''
                },
                firstDay: 1,
                year: year,
                month: month, 
                events: events,
                eventClick: function(event) {
                    History.pushState({id: event.id}, null, '?id=' + event.id);
                    return false;
                }
            });
        };
```

How can I assign `onchange` event after initialization? Something like:

```
$('#orders-calendar').on('change', function(date) { ... });
```

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with [fullcalendar](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/) but the documentation does not reveal such kind of event to be raised.

But instead of passing an array to the `events` parameter you should define a function which will perform your ajax calls and return your calendar events.

The `events` parameter indeed accepts a `function( start, end, callback ) { }` as described in the [documentation](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_function/), or if your server call returns json, you could just define the feed url as described [here](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/event_data/events_json_feed/)

**EDIT** :

The following functions `prev()`, `next()`, `prevYear()`, `nextYear()`, `today()`, `gotoDate(...)`, `incrementDate(...)` are all making call to `renderView(inc)` which itself internally calls `_renderView(inc)` which trigger the [`viewRender` event](http://arshaw.com/fullcalendar/docs/display/viewRender/).

If it does not fit your requirement, have a look in the source code to check if some  events are raised when you need. **But i would not suggest to rely on undocumented events. Undocumented events may change preventing your app to run after plugin update.**

Comment: Yes, I noticied that, just thought maybe I just couldn't find some event... Anyway I added a new variable that defines if events array was filled or not